# Existence of a Particular $L^1$ Function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I hope this question hasn't already been posted before in some other form (I couldn't find it, so if it has, please pardon me).  I found this question on an old qualifier, but I am completely lost as to how to even begin.  My only thoughts at this point are to somehow construct $h$ from some nicer dense functions, but I am not sure how to proceed even with that.

If you have any hints, thoughts, suggestions, or possible solutions, I would welcome your input.

Here is how it appears (verbatim):

"Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $T:X \to X$ be measurable, such that, if $E \in M$, $\mu(E)=0$ then $\mu(T^{-1}(E))=0$.  Prove that there exists $h \in L^{1}(\mu)$ such that

$$ \int f \circ T \, d\mu = \int fh \, d\mu$$

for all $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$."

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Comment: Don't $\mu$ need to be $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: I looked at that some time back.  I'm afraid I'm still a bit lost.  Do you think you could expand your hint, even a little, to get me started?

Comment: @fxy: $\mu\circ T^{-1}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: @user251257: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: For this statement to be true you actually need to assume $\mu$ is finite: try $f = 1$.

Comment: oh right, $f$ is $L^\infty$, not $L^1$.

Comment: Another way if to show that the LHS functional is a weak* continuous on $L^\infty$.